# VBOX on ubuntu Could not read from Boot Medium! System Halted Error

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox

im using virtual box on ubuntu . and win xp as a guest
i facing a problem im getting 
"Could not read from Boot Medium! System Halted Error"
here is a pic of my vb settings for that vmacine 
[image]

i had been using vbox rom about a year and i'm pressy sure that i had mounted the iso
beside that win 7 had never made this problem and i used that same way to make the XP vm
and i had tried to uncheck the floppy and i made sure that the boot order is correct still no luck
any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the virtual machine is booting from the correct device. When you turn on the machine press <kbd>F12</kbd> to enter the boot selection then press <kbd>C</kbd> to choose CD-ROM.

In my experience when a virtual machine complains about inability to read the boot medium it usually means that the vm hard drive's partition table has become corrupted, or the vm hard drive file itself has become corrupted. However since you have yet to install the OS I would propose that perhaps your iso is corrupt. Just a thought.

Download link for Windows XP Professional SP3, should you desire a new iso:

[Windows XP Professional Service pack 3](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/e/9/ee9d0116-c9fe-4fc2-b59c-406cbfb6d515/xpsp3_5512.080413-2113_usa_x86fre_spcd.iso)

Comment: I've just noticed that your image shows an iso in the cd-rom drive but no virtual hard drive to install to. You will need to add a virtual hard drive.